# ¿Para qué se usan llaves en los parámetros de una función en javascript?

Tags: javascript, funciones

Revisando un [código en github](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/anchor/__tests__/Anchor.test.js) hallé la siguiente prueba unitaria:

```
 it('should update links when link href update', async () => {
    let anchorInstance = null;
    function AnchorUpdate({ href }) {
      return (
        <Anchor
          ref={c => {
            anchorInstance = c;
          }}
        >
          <Link href={href} title="API" />
        </Anchor>
      );
    }
    const wrapper = mount(<AnchorUpdate href="#API" />);
```

No entiendo para qué sirven las llaves, ¿están convirtiendo el parámetro en un objeto?

Comment: es codigo de React , basicamente creas el html, Anchor debe ser un componente de React al igual que Link

Comment: lo sé, la pregunta es acerca de la sintaxis en `function AnchorUpdate({ href })`

Comment: Las llaves es para hacer destructuring, a esa función le llega un objeto y necesita quedarse solo con la propiedad `href` puedes leer algo al respecto aquí https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6, o aqui https://davidwalsh.name/destructuring-function-arguments

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas y que caso tendría poner únicamente un valor si coincidiría con todo el objeto no?

Comment: Si pasas un objeto por ejemplo {data: [], success: true, href: 'probando'} y necesitas solo href entonces pones { href }

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas adelante, haz la repuesta, es bueno saberlo :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Las llaves es para hacer `destructuring`, a esa función le llega un objeto y necesita quedarse solo con la propiedad `href` puedes leer algo al respecto [aquí](https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6) o [aqui](https://davidwalsh.name/destructuring-function-arguments). Por ejemplo, si pasas un objeto: `{data: [], success: true, href: 'probando'}` y necesitas solo `href` entonces pones `{ href }` en el parámetro de tu función, si necesitaras capturar su valor pero llamar a la variable con otro nombre seria `{ href: miHref }` y con esto `miHref` tendria el valor de la propiedad `href` que venia en el parametro de esa función.